# What does " \t\r\n\a" stand for?

Tags: c, escaping

I know what a delimiter is, but what does the string `" \t\r\n\a"` stand for in the example below?

```c
#define DELIMITER " \t\r\n\a"
```

Comment: Looks like a `DEFINE` of set of possible delimiters used/checked for later: space, tab, carriage return, new line, alert/beep

Comment: It's a string literal containing four different whitespace characters (space, tab, carriage return, linefeed) and the "alert" character.  Most likely later code will treat any of the characters in this string as delimeters...

Comment: Looks like *white-space* characters to me. Tab, carriage-return, newline and (strangely enough) "audible bell" (alert). The escape `\v` would have made more sense instead of `\a`. [Here's a list of all stadnard escapes in C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape).

Comment: Typically, such a string would be passed as the second argument to `strtok`, or similar string parsing functions.

Comment: It could be passed to `strspn()` and `strcspn` for parsing strings.  It can also be used to check characters with `strchr(DELIMITER, ch);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\t = tab
\r = carriage  return
\n = newline
\a = alert (bell)
```

Looks like the author was creating a preprocessor DEFINE containing these common delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

Those are [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C):

- `\t`: tab
- `\r`: carriage return
- `\n`: line feed (new line)
- `\a`: system bell

Answer (score 2):

`" \t\r\n\a"` is a character array containing:

• a space

```
" \t\r\n\a"
 ^
```

• a tab character (ASCII value 9)

```
" \t\r\n\a"
  ^^
```

• a carriage return character (ASCII value 13)

```
" \t\r\n\a"
    ^^
```

• a newline (ASCII value 10)

```
" \t\r\n\a"
      ^^
```

• a bell ("**alert**") character (ASCII value 7)

```
" \t\r\n\a"
        ^^
```

and a **NULL** terminator (ASCII value 0) `'\0'` - not written in the code, but all strings have one.

Answer (score 1):

This the characters for separating tokens in a string, which are usually referred to as delimiters.

The #define command is a preprocessing command to the C compiler to create a macro variable.

[C](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) and
[GNU manual](http://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/constants/create_define.php)

The first character is a space

The remaining are escapes:

```
\t = tab
\r = carriage return
\n = new line
\a = alert
```

[C escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)